# How to name comparison predicate function to sort vector

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at C++ and have a question regarding sorting a vector of a class object.  I've done a lot of research online but can't seem to figure out the answer.  My problem is that I want to have multiple predicate comparison functions that I can name, as I need to have the user be able to choose from a menu which private member variable/component of the vector to sort on.  I'm able to get a predicate comparison function with an overloaded operator to work ok, but when I try and name the function, I can't seem to get it to compile without a bunch of errors (which I'll post farther down underneath the appropriate code).

When the code's run, a vector of a BookData object is created by a function that reads a text file.  Function prototype in main:

```
vector<BookData> createVector();
```

Function call in main:

```
vector<BookData> books = createVector();
```

createVector function definition:

```
vector<BookData> createVector()
{
    const int LENGTH = 81;
    char input[LENGTH];
    vector<BookData> fBooks;
    string vBookTitle, vIsbn, vAuthor, vPublisher, vDateAdded;
    int vQtyOnHand;
    double vWholesale, vRetail;
    BookData *books1;
    books1 = new BookData;
    fstream dataFile("Serendipity.data");
    if (dataFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!dataFile.eof())
        {
            dataFile.getline(input, LENGTH, '\t');
            vBookTitle = input;
            books1->setTitle(vBookTitle);
            dataFile.getline(input, LENGTH, '\t');
            vAuthor = input;
            books1->setAuthor(vAuthor);
            dataFile.getline(input, LENGTH, '\t');
            vPublisher = input;
            books1->setPub(vPublisher);
            dataFile.getline(input, LENGTH, '\t');
            vIsbn = input;
            books1->setIsbn(vIsbn);
            dataFile >> vQtyOnHand;
            books1->setQty(vQtyOnHand);
            dataFile >> vWholesale;
            books1->setWholesale(vWholesale);
            dataFile >> vRetail;
            books1->setRetail(vRetail);
            dataFile.ignore();
            dataFile.getline(input, LENGTH);
            vDateAdded = input;
            books1->setDateAdded(vDateAdded);
            fBooks.push_back(*books1);
        }
    }
    return fBooks;
}
```

This is my class definition file (bookdata.h) with the working comparison function:

```
class BookData
{ 
private:
        string bookTitle, isbn, author,
            publisher, dateAdded;
        int qtyOnHand;
        double wholesale, retail;
        bool empty;     

public:
    BookData();
    bool operator< (BookData rhs);
    void printVector();
    void setTitle(string);
    void setIsbn(string);
    void setAuthor(string);
    void setPub(string);
    void setDateAdded(string);
    void setQty(int);
    void setWholesale(double);
    void setRetail(double);
    int isEmpty();
    void insertBook();
    void removeBook();
    string getTitle();
    string getIsbn();
    string getAuthor();
    string getPublisher();
    string getDateAdded();
    int getQtyOnHand();
    double getWholesale();
    double getRetail();
};
```

And this is the working function in the class implementation file (bookdata.cpp):

```
bool BookData::operator< (BookData rhs)
{
    return qtyOnHand < rhs.qtyOnHand;
}
```

And it's called like so from int main():

```
sort (books.begin(), books.end());
```

However, if I try and name the function:

```
bool compare (BookData rhs);
```

from within the class definition file and change it to this in the class implementation file:

```
bool BookData::compare (BookData rhs)
{
    return qtyOnHand < rhs.qtyOnHand;
}
```

and change the vector sort function so within main:

```
sort (books.begin(), books.end(), &BookData::compare);
```

I get an error message from the compiler:

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Any suggestions as to how I can properly name/call the sort function?

Comment: A proper name should probably indicate that it is comparing quantity-at-hand, not something else. - byQuantity? -> `sort(books.begin(), books.end(), byQuantity)`

Comment: @UncleBens- You're definitely right, this was just a test function.  Once I got them right, I was going to change them to more descriptive names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Compare` shouldn't be a member of the class (or be a `static` member or `friend` if it accesses restricted fields), and it should accept both the values to compare (whereas `operator <` uses `this` as the left value).

something like this:

```
bool compare (BookData lhs, BookData rhs)
{
    return lhs.qtyOnHand < rhs.qtyOnHand;
}
```

Using `operator<` is IMHO a better approach.

Comment: @littleadv- But then how do I both name the function and use the `operator<` in the function prototype and definition? That's where I'm running into problems.

Comment: Never mind- I took your suggestion about taking the function out of the class and that worked perfectly.  Thanks! Had to change function implementation to access private class members by using the getter function, though: `bool sortByQty (BookData lhs, BookData rhs)
{
    return lhs.getQtyOnHand() < rhs.getQtyOnHand();
}`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create a predicate as function object:

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const BookData& x, const BookData& y) const
    {
        return x < y;
    }
};
```

Note the `const` at the end of `operator()`. You can pass this object to STL algorithms as follows:

```
sort (books.begin(), books.end(), compare());
```

If you do not want to create the function object each time, you may include it as (static) member in `BookData`.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, suggest to pass-by-reference instead of pass-by-value for the parameters, like this:

```
bool compare (const BookData &lhs, const BookData &rhs)
{
  // implementation.
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it's better to pass by constant reference than value?

Comment: When I do this, I get an error `the object has type errors that are not compatible with the member function.`